# Unit testing JPA insertion in the DB

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, jpa, junit, playframework-2.0

I want to test some methods to check if they're really insert data in DB.
I'm using `play framework 2.2.1`, with and `H2` in-memory DB.
I'm also bootstrapping an application database loading an `SQL` script with some initial data for testing load queries.

I wrote an `AbstractTest` that I'm extending to have the `JPA` `EntityManager` in the tests.

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        FakeApplication app = Helpers.fakeApplication();
        Helpers.start(app);
        Option<JPAPlugin> jpaPlugin = app.getWrappedApplication().plugin(JPAPlugin.class);
        em = jpaPlugin.get().em("default");
        JPA.bindForCurrentThread(em);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        JPA.bindForCurrentThread(null);
        em.close();
    }
}
```

With this class I can easily test the load queries.

But I cannot test that a method is saving in the DB, that's because the `JPA` `Transaction` gets closed at the end of the test, so If I try to load the object I've just saved in the DB I get a `null`.

For example:

```
public class MessageServiceTest extends AbstractTest {

    public void saveTest(){
        User user = User.findById(2L, User.class);
        Interlocutor interlocutor = Interlocutor.findById(1L, Interlocutor.class);
        Conversation conversation = new Conversation();
        conversation.user = user;
        conversation.interlocutor = interlocutor;
        conversation.save();

        //I know the id of the saved object is 2
        Conversation conversantionFromDb = Conversation.findById(2L, Conversation.class);
        assertThat(conversantionFromDb.id).isEqualTo(2);
       //Null pointer the conversation object is not saved to the DB.
    }
}
```

I'm missing something?
What's the best way to test for the insertion of the data in the DB?

Comment: How do you know that the ID of the saved object is 2? Why not use conversation.getId() to use the actual, generated ID of the conversation?

Comment: @JBNizet yes I could use the `id`, but it is null until the object is saved in the DB, thing that happens at the end of the transation, the end of the test.

Comment: The call em.flush() to force the ID generation and the insert into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I need to open and close the `Transaction`. So the modified `AbstractTest` class:

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        FakeApplication app = Helpers.fakeApplication();
        Helpers.start(app);
        Option<JPAPlugin> jpaPlugin = app.getWrappedApplication().plugin(JPAPlugin.class);
        em = jpaPlugin.get().em("default");
        JPA.bindForCurrentThread(em);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        JPA.bindForCurrentThread(null);
        em.close();
    }
}
```